# How to remove space in string around ü, ä, ö in django template

Tags: django, templates, character-encoding, ckeditor

I am using django 1.11.2 and ckeditor.

Here text is displaing:

```
<p>{{ object.text|striptags|safe }}</p>
```

I am using `striptags` because I have link in link, I mean:

```
<a>
    <a></a>
</a>
```

And I recived string with space `'au ß ergew ö hnliche'`

Comment: try `{{ object.text|safe }}` only

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta nope, this is not working for me.

Comment: in general we do not use `<a>` inside another `<a>` that's a bad practice.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta yes I know, but in this case have to be like this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use {%spaceless%} tag in template